# Many threads to call same function, only one should make it

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a function (Shutdown()) which is used to terminate my windows form (does some clean up and call this.close() at the end).

In my application I have threads of execution

- The UI
- A background worker
- A timer

Each one of these can call Shutdown(), either by the user pressing a button (UI), the timer expiring (timer), or the background worker completing his task. This leads me to a worry that if the timing is really bad I can have more then one thread calling Shutdown() at the same time.

So how can I ensure that only the first one that calls it will execute it? Any subsequent calls should just be ignored as the call will end in terminating the application anyways.

Comment: Win32? Isn't there something native to C#? I was thinking some kind of lock or something - but hoping there was a better solution. Maybe message passing (state machine) style, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear from your question what the difficulty is. What have you tried? What trouble did you run into?

The obvious, trivial implementation would be something like this:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();
private bool _shuttingDown;

public void Shutdown()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        if (_shuttingDown) return;

        _shuttingDown = true;
    }

    // do work here...
}
```

Is there some reason that doesn't work in your scenario? If so, please provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, a describe precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: I have yet to cause any errors or failures, but I am worried I have just gotten lucky  if a simple lock will safeguard it then I'll do that. The goal is preventative